# When looping through object keys, why does the key get converted to a new number?

Tags: autohotkey

I have an issue, look at this code:

```
#SingleInstance, Force
SetBatchLines, -1
CoordMode, Pixel, screen

FileDelete, Log.txt

listObject := {}
listObject[4280361510] := true

for index1 in listObject
{
    FileAppend, % "Item: " . index1 . "`n", Log.txt
}
```

Which prints to the file:

```
Item: -14605786
```

Where I would expect it to print:

```
Item: 4280361510
```

Why is the property shown as `-14605786` when the index I assigned was `4280361510`?

Also:

```
if (listObject[4280361510]) {
    FileAppend, % "But 4280361510 still works. `n", Log.txt
}

if (listObject[-14605786]) {
    FileAppend, % "And -14605786 works too. `n", Log.txt
}
```

Prints to file:

```
But 4280361510 still works. 
And -14605786 works too.
```

Why do both properties act as if they're assigned to the object?

Comment: Not sure if it matters but in order to support the gdip AHK library I'm running on the 32 bit ANSI version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`4280361510` and `-14605786` *are the same number* - in 32-bit arithmetic.  Signed 32-bit numbers wrap around and become negative at about 2 billion (2<sup>31</sup>).  This number has almost wrapped around a second time, in which case it would become positive again.